# How to debug a Coldfusion Bad Gateway error?

Tags: coldfusion, bad-gateway

I'm trying to setup custom CFX tags for Coldfusion 11 but when I try to make a call to one of them the server just throws this 502 error:

[image: Coldfusion 502 error]

I've already looked at the logs in Colfusion administration panel but am getting **no entries** for this specific issue. This only happens if I call a page with a custom tag... other CFM pages work fine.

Does anyone know how to debug this type of error in Coldfusion 11?

Comment: Can the cfx_ be replaced with something newer?

Comment: For that type of error, the logs you can see in CF Admin aren't going to help, because the request isn't getting far enough. You may be able to get some more information to debug by looking at the lower level log files such as `coldfusion-out.log` and `isapi_redirect.log` - I don't have access to a CF11 instance but I believe this would normally be found at `/ColdFusion11/cfusion/logs` if you haven't specified a custom log directory.

Comment: @JamesAMohler, it's a legacy application. Just trying to making it work on my local enviorment.

Comment: @SevRoberts, there's nothing in `coldfusion-out.log` pointing out to the error and no `isapi_redirect.log` in log files :(

Comment: Event log? What exactly is the cfx tag?

Comment: @SOS, which event log? I've just enabled ColdFusion Event Gateway Services and it's not catching up the error either. The CFX tag is a SAP connection/integration.

Comment: The Windows event logs. Is this cfx publically available?

Comment: @SOS, the CFX is private! Also there's no information on Windows Event Log however if I run "colfusion.exe -start -console" in CMD and call the problematic page I get this exception - https://imgur.com/a/A4tl1GF - and it crashes the server.

Comment: @user3466681 - Okay. I assume the DLL is 64bit, correct? There's not much useful info there, aside from what looks like an "access denied error". 1. What does the referenced crash log contain hs_error_pid31508.log? 2. Is the app running in a CF sandbox?

Comment: 3. Also, did the CFX tag ever work - under any version of CF?

Comment: @SOS, the CFX is working in QA/PROD enviorment. Not sure if it's running in a CF sandbox or not. Here are the logs https://pastebin.com/5eLrpNs5 can you please take a loot a them and see if you find anything?

Comment: I'm not adept at reading dumps. Nothing jumped out at me other than the "access denied" error, 0xc0000005.  If it works in another environment, I'd be looking at what's different in yours, CF Version, Java Version, Windows Version, Sandbox/No Sandbox. Ideally you should be running a mirror of QA/Prod.  Are you?